# How to get return Value from a nested promises

Tags: rest, reactjs, request, promise, ecmascript-6

I am having some Issues with returning data from nested promises and callbacks within, From my component i call Api method to find the checkid first, when i recieve checkid, i will check the status with that id. Another thing here, when i check status, I am using third party service, so data wont be returned immidiately. So i call the status api max 10times (with a time out of 3 sec) until i receive my data. 
here is my first implementation.

deviceService consits of simple API methods using request library

```
    For Ex: 

      const deviceService ={
        fetchID(param1){
            request.get('https://.....')
        }
      }
```

//In react Component File. I call API as

```
       API.getDeviceLockStatus(param1).then(data => {
           //I need data after i reciving the value from 3rd party server
          if (data) {
             //DO SOMETHING
           }
       });
```

API.js File:

```
            var API = {
                getDeviceLockStatus(param1) {        
                    return deviceService.fetchID(param1).then(checkID => {

                        console.log('Got checkID here')
                        if (checkID) {
                            callStatus(checkID);
                        }
                    }, handleError);
                }
            }

            function callStatus(checkID) {
                return deviceService.fetchStatus(checkID).then(status => {
                    // If i receive the response from 3rd party Server i will have status.body.isAvailable = true (or False)
                    // if Not i will recieve status with status.checkID (this checkID is what i have supplied)
                    if (status.body.isAvailable) {
                        return status
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(callBackFunction(status.checkID), 3000)
                    }
                },han)
            }
            callBackFunction(checkID) {
                callStatus(checkID);
            }
            function handleError(){
                // Error will be Handled
            }
```

So Issue is When i call API.getDeviceLockStatus(param1).. It returns undefined immidiately.

Can some one help me to do it better way or return actual value after it fetched real data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `It returns undefined immidiately.` - you're not returning anything in the `.then` block, so that's what the returned Promise will resolve to ... perhaps you meant `callStatus(checkID);` in that block ... but then, `callStatus` will not work like you expect if it goes through the `setTimeout` code in there

Comment: Yeah, that one issue i am struggling with, As you said, i added return to callStatus(checkId) in both places and also before setTimeout loop. Still gets nothing

Comment: you can't return setTimeout and expect to get a Promise ... that `callStatus` function looks to be recursive (but not in a bad way) - so you'll need to rewrite the code a bit

Answer (score 2):

looking at API.js, there's not too much to change

```
var API = {
    getDeviceLockStatus(param1) {
        return deviceService.fetchID(param1).then(checkID => {
            console.log('Got checkID here')
            if (checkID) {
                return callStatus(checkID); // added return
            }
        }, handleError);
    }
}

function callStatus(checkID) {
    return deviceService.fetchStatus(checkID).then(status => {
        // If i receive the response from 3rd party Server i will have status.body.isAvailable = true (or False)
        // if Not i will recieve status with status.checkID (this checkID is what i have supplied)
        if (status.body.isAvailable) {
            return status
        } else { // here one way to do a simple delay/retry with a Promise
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
            }).then(function() {
                return callStatus(status.checkID);
            });
        }
    }, handleError)
}

function handleError() {
    // Error will be Handled
}
```

Comment: Dude, You are Just AWESOME. I was about to rewrite this whole damn thing.

Comment: If this is the answer, you should probably accept it.